# Having Unknown error

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In my app there are activities in which I used to call the data from the parse server but suddenly after opening any activity the app crashed and after restarting the app it opened

**Four.java**

```
@ParseClassName("Four")
public class Four extends ParseObject{
    public Four(){    
    }

    public String getFourc(){
        return getString("fourc");
    }

    public void setFourc(String fourc){
        put("fourc", fourc);
    }
}
```

**Four Adapter**

```
  public class FourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Four> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Four> mFours;

    public FourAdapter(Context context, List<Four> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.four_row_item, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mFours = objects;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.four_row_item, null);
        }

        Four four = mFours.get(position);

        TextView descriptionView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.four_fourc);

        descriptionView.setText(four.getFourc());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**FourActivity**

```
public class FourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mListView;
    private FourAdapter mAdapter;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_four);
        //noinspection ConstantConditions

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.gpsicon);

        mAdapter = new FourAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Four>());
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.four_list);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        ParseQuery<Four> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Four.class);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Four>() {
            public void done(List<Four> fours, ParseException error) {
                if (fours != null) {
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < fours.size(); i++) {
                        mAdapter.add(fours.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_four, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_notice) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, FonActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.home) {
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**LogCat error**

```
09-23 23:07:11.776    2400-2400/com.school.gurunanakpublicschool E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.parse.ParseObject cannot be cast to com.school.gurunanakpublicschool.Four
        at com.school.gurunanakpublicschool.FourAdapter.getView(FourAdapter.java:29)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

App crashes at any activity just randomly there are many more activities like this Please help me.

Comment: App crashes at any activity just randomly there are many more activities like this Please help me

Comment: clearly showing `java.lang.ClassCastException` check `FourAdapter`.

Comment: What type of error I dont know because on opening activity four then it is easily going on but the problem comes when the same type of other ctivity is launched then on fourth or fifth launch activity crashes its is random

Comment: com.parse.ParseObject cannot be cast to com.school.gurunanakpublicschool.Four .. you have a casting problem ParseObject is not a Four,